# typescript get hostname, protocol, port from a string containging url

Tags: javascript, url, typescript

if I have a string like http://localhost:8080
and I want to extract the different parts of the of url, like the protocol http,  domain name (localhost) and port (8080), what is the best way to do in typescript?

I can do a simple parse of the string to get the different values. But not sure if that is the best/cleanest way to do it. Should I first convert this string to a valid URL (using some library) and then get the hostname, protocol and port from it? Java would have such libraries that would easily let me do that but how do I achieve the same with typescript?

Comment: What's your environment? ([Example](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html))

Comment: angular 2 is my front end and backend is node

Comment: First of all, asking for typescript won't yeld much results for you. Ask for JavaScript;
Second of all, what technology you are asking about? Browser, server, IoT?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
let url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
console.log(url.protocol); // http:
console.log(url.host); // localhost:8080
console.log(url.port); // 8080
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20url%20%3D%20new%20URL(%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(url.protocol)%3B%20%2F%2F%20http%3A%0D%0Aconsole.log(url.host)%3B%20%2F%2F%20localhost%3A8080%0D%0Aconsole.log(url.port)%3B%20%2F%2F%208080))

It is not implemented in all browsers but you can find polyfills for it if you want to work with it.

---

#### Edit

In node you can do this:

```
import { URL } from "url";

let url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
console.log(url.protocol); // http:
console.log(url.host); // localhost:8080
console.log(url.port); // 8080
```

If you get this compilaiton error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'url'

Then you need the node definitions:

```
npm install @types/node
```

Comment: It doesnt give me compilation error. However, while running, it throws exception: "URL is undefined". Am I missing something? I am implementing it on node backend

Comment: It is supported in node: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html, but you need to import it: `const url = require('url');`

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: import { URL } from "url";   gives me compilation error "[ts] Module '"url"' has no exported member 'URL'.

Comment: Weird. That code compiles/runs perfectly well for me. What version of node and it's definition files are you using? What do you get when you run `cat node_modules/@types/node/package.json| grep _id` ?

Comment: "_id": "@types/node@6.0.71",    Also it looks like import should be like?:   import { Url } from 'url';   But then it wont let me do a new Url(..)

Comment: No, it should be `URL` (https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url), but that's seems to be something new to node 7. In node 6 you'll need to use `url.parse` (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) Or you can update your node version...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) in this purposes

```
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://localhost:8080";

console.log(a.protocol);
console.log(a.host);
console.log(a.port);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node.js 6 or lower,

```
import * as url from 'url';
const { protocol, host, port } = url.parse('http://localhost:8080');
console.log(protocol); // http:
console.log(host); // localhost:8080
console.log(port); // 8080
```